# Xively Embedded C Memory Footprint

Tags: xively

Does anyone know the memory requirement for the Xively Embedded C library? RAM and Flash size?
I intend to use a low cost micro-controller with limited memory - 16KB flash and 1KB SDRAM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile the library for the taget chip first. The size of the binary depends on how efficient are the optimisations your compiler applies. When you do find out what the size is out of the box and in case you need to make it smaller and not too sure how, please do submit an [issue ticket](https://github.com/xively/libxively/issues/new).